# How to sort an alphanumeric character object?

Tags: r

I want to apply a function on some files using a loop. I read all files within a folder:

```
> tt <- list.files("/PATH.to.FILES/", full.names=TRUE) 
> tt
 [1] /PATH.to.FILES/AA.22.1 
 [2] /PATH.to.FILES/AA.22.10
 [3] /PATH.to.FILES/AA.22.11
 [4] /PATH.to.FILES/AA.22.12
 [5] /PATH.to.FILES/AA.22.13
 [6] /PATH.to.FILES/AA.22.2 
 [7] /PATH.to.FILES/AA.22.3 
 [8] /PATH.to.FILES/AA.22.4 
 [9] /PATH.to.FILES/AA.22.5 
 [10] /PATH.to.FILES/AA.22.6 
 [11] /PATH.to.FILES/AA.22.7 
 [12] /PATH.to.FILES/AA.22.8 
 [13] /PATH.to.FILES/AA.22.9
```

I want to pass this to a loop in the order determined by the last number in the name of the files (i.e. the number that comes after `22`). Currently, as you see, after `1`, there is `10, 11, 12, 13`. I want it to be like this:

```
> tt
[1] /PATH.to.FILES/AA.22.1 
[2] /PATH.to.FILES/AA.22.2 
[3] /PATH.to.FILES/AA.22.3 
[4] /PATH.to.FILES/AA.22.4 
[5] /PATH.to.FILES/AA.22.5 
[6] /PATH.to.FILES/AA.22.6 
[7] /PATH.to.FILES/AA.22.7 
[8] /PATH.to.FILES/AA.22.8 
[9] /PATH.to.FILES/AA.22.9
[10] /PATH.to.FILES/AA.22.10
[11] /PATH.to.FILES/AA.22.11
[12] /PATH.to.FILES/AA.22.12
[13] /PATH.to.FILES/AA.22.13
```

I tried `mixedsort(tt)`, but it did not work. I would appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`as.numeric` on the result of subbing out everything up to the last decimal point:

```
> tt[ order( as.numeric( sub("^.+\\.", "", tt) ) ) ]
 [1] "/PATH.to.FILES/AA.22.1 " "/PATH.to.FILES/AA.22.2 "
 [3] "/PATH.to.FILES/AA.22.3 " "/PATH.to.FILES/AA.22.4 "
 [5] "/PATH.to.FILES/AA.22.5 " "/PATH.to.FILES/AA.22.6 "
 [7] "/PATH.to.FILES/AA.22.7 " "/PATH.to.FILES/AA.22.8 "
 [9] "/PATH.to.FILES/AA.22.9"  "/PATH.to.FILES/AA.22.10"
[11] "/PATH.to.FILES/AA.22.11" "/PATH.to.FILES/AA.22.12"
[13] "/PATH.to.FILES/AA.22.13"
```

If you wanted to match the second to last item in strings separated by dots it would be bit more complicated. I've illustrated one possible approach for matching "digit" characters prior to removing 'dot'[alpha] endings.

```
 sub("(^.+\\.)(\\d+)(\\.[A-Z]+$)", "\\2", "AA.BB.$i.2.CC")
 [1] "2"
```

You need to look up `?regex`.

Comment: Could you please explain a little the `sub` part? For example, how would it be with strings like `AA.BB.$i.2.CC` ?

Comment: You would get `CC` because it is "greedy", i.e. it matches the maximum length to the string that fits the pattern describe in words as "everything (that's the ".+") from the start of the string ("^" )up to and including a "dot" ("\\.")

Answer (score 1):

This is lexicographic sorting which means basically the language treats the variables as strings and compares character by character ("200" is greater than "19999" because '2' is greater than '1')

To fix this you can

- ensure that the values are treated as integers;
- prepend '0' to the strings so all have equal lengths (only viable when you know the max value). This is why you'll see episode numberings on media files (S1E01) with a prepended 0 so a lexicographic sort doesn't mess things up and allows programs to simply play/display in alphabetical order;
- or make a custom comparator that first compares the length of the strings (shorter strings being smaller integers) and when they are equal compare the lexicographically (careful about leading '0').

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be related to the fact that `mixedsort` relies on `gsub` to isolate numerics from character strings. Unfortunately, `.` is a special character for `gsub`and the matching they use to isolate numerics does not like it at all!

However, if you are willing to replace all dots by something more likeable for `mixedsort` (like a `*` e.g., which should be also risky, since it is also a special character), it will work:

```
x <- c("/PATH.to.FILES/AA.22.1", "/PATH.to.FILES/AA.22.10", "/PATH.to.FILES/AA.22.11", 
"/PATH.to.FILES/AA.22.12", "/PATH.to.FILES/AA.22.13", "/PATH.to.FILES/AA.22.2", 
"/PATH.to.FILES/AA.22.3", "/PATH.to.FILES/AA.22.4", "/PATH.to.FILES/AA.22.5", 
"/PATH.to.FILES/AA.22.6", "/PATH.to.FILES/AA.22.7", "/PATH.to.FILES/AA.22.8", 
"/PATH.to.FILES/AA.22.9")

x_star <- gsub("\\.", "*", x)
sorted_x_star <- gtools::mixedsort(x_star)
sorted_x <-  gsub("\\*", ".", sorted_x_star)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there's an easier way but this is the approach I would take immediately.

```
tt[order(sapply(strsplit(tt, ".", fixed = TRUE), function(x) as.numeric(x[5])))]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a function that should work

```
#sample data
pp<-c("/PATH.to.FILES/AA.22.1", "/PATH.to.FILES/AA.22.10", "/PATH.to.FILES/AA.22.11", 
"/PATH.to.FILES/AA.22.12", "/PATH.to.FILES/AA.22.13", "/PATH.to.FILES/AA.22.2", 
"/PATH.to.FILES/AA.22.3", "/PATH.to.FILES/AA.22.4", "/PATH.to.FILES/AA.22.5", 
"/PATH.to.FILES/AA.22.6", "/PATH.to.FILES/AA.22.7", "/PATH.to.FILES/AA.22.8", 
"/PATH.to.FILES/AA.22.9")
```

and here's our sorting function

```
multiorder <- function(x, seps="[./]") {
    do.call(order, 
        read.table(text=sapply(strsplit(pp, seps), 
    paste, collapse="\t")))
}
```

test it out

```
pp[multiorder(pp)]

#  [1] "/PATH.to.FILES/AA.22.1"  "/PATH.to.FILES/AA.22.2" 
#  [3] "/PATH.to.FILES/AA.22.3"  "/PATH.to.FILES/AA.22.4" 
#  [5] "/PATH.to.FILES/AA.22.5"  "/PATH.to.FILES/AA.22.6" 
#  [7] "/PATH.to.FILES/AA.22.7"  "/PATH.to.FILES/AA.22.8" 
#  [9] "/PATH.to.FILES/AA.22.9"  "/PATH.to.FILES/AA.22.10"
# [11] "/PATH.to.FILES/AA.22.11" "/PATH.to.FILES/AA.22.12"
# [13] "/PATH.to.FILES/AA.22.13"
```

The idea is that we split the values on `/` and `.` and treat each column. We send it though `read.table` so that each "column" is converted to the proper number/character data.type. Then we order based on all the columns. This will work with a very general case of file names as long as the parts to be sorted are all delimited somehow. This does assume that all the records have the same number of "virtual columns". If this is not the case, you would want to subset to the part where they do share columns and sort based on that.